# Play Framework 2.3.8 compilation error

Tags: java, compilation, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I've some problems with Play Framework could you help me please ?

I've tried the following:

```
  C:\activator new myFirstProject play-scala
  C:\cd myFirstProject  
  C:\myFirstProject\ activator
  [myFirstProject] run
```

it works well (compilation ok, and access through browser ok too)

Now if I try the same with the java template, it does not work because of a compilation error...

```
  C:\activator new myFirstProject play-java
  C:\cd myFirstProject  
  C:\myFirstProject\ activator
  [myFirstProject] run
```

log/error :

```
    C:\>activator new myFirstProject play-java

    Fetching the latest list of templates...

    OK, application "myFirstProject" is being created using the "play-java"
    template
    .

    To run "myFirstProject" from the command line, "cd myFirstProject" then:
    C:\\myFirstProject/activator run

    To run the test for "myFirstProject" from the command line, "cd
    myFirstProject"
    then:
    C:\\myFirstProject/activator test

    To run the Activator UI for "myFirstProject" from the command line, "cd
    myFirstP
    roject" then:
    C:\\myFirstProject/activator ui


    C:\>cd myFirstProject

    C:\myFirstProject>activator
    [info] Loading project definition from C:\myFirstProject\project
    [info] Updating {file:/C:/myFirstProject/project/}myfirstproject-build...
    [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support_2.10;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.2-GA ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.2.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.mozilla#rhino;1.7R4 ...
      [info] Resolving com.google.javascript#closure-compiler;v20130603 ...
      [info] Resolving org.json#json;20090211 ...
      [info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm-agent;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.175 ...
      [info] Resolving net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-twirl;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-compiler_2.10;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.10;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-parser_2.10;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;3.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;3.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.tukaani#xz;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.vafer#jdeb;1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7 ...
      [info] Resolving org.tukaani#xz;1.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-core;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-model;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-utils;3.0.17 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-settings;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-settings-builder;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-interpolation;1.19 ...
      [info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-annotations;1.5.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.sonatype.plexus#plexus-sec-dispatcher;1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.sonatype.plexus#plexus-cipher;1.7 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-repository-metadata;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-artifact;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-plugin-api;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.sisu#org.eclipse.sisu.plexus;0.0.0.M5 ...
      [info] Resolving javax.enterprise#cdi-api;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving javax.annotation#jsr250-api;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving javax.inject#javax.inject;1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.sonatype.sisu#sisu-guice;3.1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.sisu#org.eclipse.sisu.inject;0.0.0.M5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-classworlds;2.5.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-model-builder;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-aether-provider;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-api;0.9.0.M2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-spi;0.9.0.M2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-util;0.9.0.M2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-impl;0.9.0.M2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.ant#ant;1.9.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.ant#ant-launcher;1.9.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.bouncycastle#bcpg-jdk15on;1.51 ...
      [info] Resolving org.bouncycastle#bcprov-jdk15on;1.51 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-js-engine;1.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe#jse_2.10;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-contrib_2.10;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-remote_2.10;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.8.0.Final ...
      [info] Resolving com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;2.5.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.uncommons.maths#uncommons-maths;1.2.2a ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-cluster_2.10;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving
    com.typesafe.akka#akka-persistence-experimental_2.10;2.3.2 ..
    .
      [info] Resolving org.iq80.leveldb#leveldb;0.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.iq80.leveldb#leveldb-api;0.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-all;1.7 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni;1.7 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.hawtjni#hawtjni-runtime;1.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-osx;1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-linux32;1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-linux64;1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-win32;1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-win64;1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving io.apigee.trireme#trireme-core;0.7.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.2 ...
      [info] Resolving io.apigee.trireme#trireme-node10src;0.7.5 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.2.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-scala_2.10;1.1.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-simple;1.7.7 ...
      [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe#npm_2.10;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#npm;1.3.26 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#webjars-locator;0.14 ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.3.3 ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.3.0 ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.3.3 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-web;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-webdriver;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe#webdriver_2.10;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-client;1.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-can;1.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-io;1.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-util;1.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-http;1.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-httpx;1.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.jvnet.mimepull#mimepull;1.9.4 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 ...
      [info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
      [info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
      [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.2.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.14 ...
      [info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
      [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.20 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.13 ...
      [info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-coffeescript;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#coffee-script-node;1.7.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#mkdirp;0.3.5 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-less;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#less-node;1.6.0-1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#source-map;0.1.31-2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#amdefine;0.1.0-1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-jshint;1.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#jshint-node;2.4.1-1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#underscorejs;1.5.2-2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#console-browserify;0.1.6-1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-rjs;1.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#rjs;2.1.11-1-trireme ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-mocha;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#mocha;1.17.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#debug;0.7.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webjars#diff;1.0.7 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.10;0.4.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0 ...
      [info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
    [info] Done updating.
    [info] Set current project to myFirstProject (in build
    file:/C:/myFirstProject/)

    [myFirstProject] $
    [myFirstProject] $ run
    [info] Updating {file:/C:/myFirstProject/}root...
    [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.2-GA ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.11;0.7 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.2.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.6 ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.3.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.1 ...
      [info] Resolving
    org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.1 ..
    .
      [info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.9.3.Final ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.netty#netty-http-pipelining;1.1.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.6 ...
      [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.1 ...
      [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.4 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.11;2.3.4 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9 ...
      [info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
      [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
      [info] Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.13 ...
      [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;5.0.3.Final ...
      [info] Resolving javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final ...
      [info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.1.1.GA ...
      [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#classmate;1.0.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.2.0.Final ...
      [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-context;4.0.3.RELEASE ...
      [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-core;4.0.3.RELEASE ...
      [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-beans;4.0.3.RELEASE ...
      [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.19.0-GA ...
      [info] Resolving org.reflections#reflections;0.9.8 ...
      [info] Resolving dom4j#dom4j;1.6.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-servlet-api;8.0.5 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
      [info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.175 ...
      [info] Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-ebean_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm;3.3.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm-agent;3.2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving
    org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.F
    inal ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-core;2.6.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ws_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.ning#async-http-client;1.8.15 ...
      [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2 ...
      [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
      [info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-core_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-matcher_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-common_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.11;7.0.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-concurrent_2.11;7.0.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.11;7.0.6 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-junit_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-mock_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-core;1.9.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.objenesis#objenesis;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-matcher-extra_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-analysis_2.11;2.3.12 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.specs2#classycle;1.4.3 ...
      [info] Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.11-RC1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-festassert;0.9.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;0.9.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-java;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-android-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;2.1_3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.json#json;20080701 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.1 ...
      [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0 ...
      [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-chrome-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-htmlunit-driver;2.39.0
    ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.13 ...
      [info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
      [info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.3.1 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.13 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.19 ...
      [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.11 ...
      [info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.2 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
      [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-ie-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-iphone-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.webbitserver#webbit;0.4.14 ...
      [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;2.39.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-assert;1.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.11;2.3.8 ...
      [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-doc_2.11;1.1.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.pegdown#pegdown;1.4.0 ...
      [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.5 ...
      [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm;4.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-tree;4.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-analysis;4.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-util;4.1 ...
      [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.1 ...
      [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.2 ...
      [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
    [info] Done updating.

    --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

    [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

    (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
    --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

    [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

    (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

    [info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to
    C:\myFirstProject\target\
    scala-2.11\classes...
    [error] C:\myFirstProject\app\controllers\Application.java:3: error:
    package pla
    y does not exist
    [error] import play.*;
    [error] ^
    [error] C:\myFirstProject\app\controllers\Application.java:4: error:
    package pla
    y.mvc does not exist
    [error] import play.mvc.*;
    [error] ^
    [error] C:\myFirstProject\app\controllers\Application.java:8: error:
    cannot find
     symbol
    [error] public class Application extends Controller {
    [error]                                  ^
    [error]   symbol: class Controller
    [error] C:\myFirstProject\app\controllers\Application.java:10: error:
    cannot fin
    d symbol
    [error]     public static Result index() {
    [error]                   ^
    [error]   symbol:   class Result
    [error]   location: class Application
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ReverseAssets.cl
    ass: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type
    'ScalaSignature':
    class file for scala.reflect.ScalaSignature not found
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ReverseApplicati
    on.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type
    'ScalaSignatu
    re'
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\javascript\Rever
    seAssets.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type
    'ScalaS
    ignature'
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\javascript\Rever
    seApplication.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in
    type 'S
    calaSignature'
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ref\ReverseAsset
    s.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type
    'ScalaSignatur
    e'
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ref\ReverseAppli
    cation.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type
    'ScalaSig
    nature'
    [error]
    C:\myFirstProject\target\scala-2.11\classes\views\html\index.class: warn
    ing: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
    [error] C:\myFirstProject\app\controllers\Application.java:11: error:
    cannot acc
    ess Html
    [error]         return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    [error]                               ^
    [error]   class file for play.twirl.api.Html not found
    [error] 5 errors
    [error] 7 warnings
    [error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
    [error] application -

    ! @6lob5471k - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

    play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: package
    play
    does not exist]
            at
    play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:
    27) ~[na:na]
            at
    play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:
    27) ~[na:na]
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
            at
    play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:
    49) ~[na:na]
            at
    play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:
    44) ~[na:na]
    [warn] play - No application found at invoker init
```

I'm using windows 8, activator 1.3.2 and I've tried with various version of java 1.8 and 1.7. What's really strange, is that it works well on other computers with the same environnement (windows 8, activator 1.3.2 and java 1.8). How could I solve this problem ??

Thank you very much

Comment: Having the same issue here! I tried adding the xalan serializer, which failed to be added to the dependencies in the build.sbt file but still the error occurs. The guys at Typesafe are really starting to piss me off!

Answer (score 1):

Go open your `project/plugins.sbt` file and check if you have this line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")
```